# Error when execute cucumberjs with same step definition for different features

Tags: node.js, gherkin, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

```
// signin.test.js
...
this.Then(/^I should be redirected to my dashboard$/, function() {
  var self = this;
  return this.browser
    .getUrl().then(function(eUrl) {
      eUrl.should.be.equal(self.url);
    })
    .end();
});
...
```

And this is the exactly same step for sign-up feature.

```
// signup.test.js
...
this.Then(/^I should be redirected to my dashboard$/, function() {
  var self = this;
  return this.browser
    .getUrl().then(function(eUrl) {
      eUrl.should.be.equal(self.url);
    })
    .end();
});
...
```

Running the test, I got this error for `sign-in` feature:

[image]

However, the test will run properly if I

- Option 1: comment out the above js part of signin.test.js or signup.test.js.
- Option 2: change the description to another text to make them different, e.g `I should be redirected to my dashboard 12345`.

Is that a bug of `cucumberjs`?

Is there anyway to workaround this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the error is indicating an undefined step definition? It seems more likely to me that it's reporting an ambiguous step definition. As of `v0.9.0`, [ambiguous step definitions are no longer allowed](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/6c0c4c94710f23607dfece6f58a1a91d97a04316/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes):

```
0.9.0

Breaking changes

* catch ambiguous step definitions (Charlie Rudolph)
* remove use of domain (Charlie Rudolph)
```

In any case, implementing identical blocks of code is a bad practice that you should try to avoid. See the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). I would suggest you take Option 1 and delete the duplicate step definition entirely.